# Expand to Full Document Mode

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm trying to make the project tracker app have the option of full document mode because when I add more columns it doesn't seem to scale well. Ex. I added about 4 more columns and I can no longer select the calendar if the date is the last column. I was looking at the example to expand to full mode here: https://alliancels.quip.com/dev/liveapps/recipes#expand-to-full-document-mode
I'm not sure this example is correct because it mentions a wrapper div that is not in the example. Where can I find more examples of how to convert a quip app to full document mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect you to find the relevant information and more examples by reviewing or searching the [Quip Developer Reference Documention](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation).

Comment: This is mentioned in the recipe "The key for full document mode is quip.apps.getViewportDimensions(), the complete code for the wrapper div looks like this".
I may be missing it, but I see no reference to getViewportDimensions in the Developer Documentation.

Comment: @Jose  `getViewportDimensions()` appears to be a javascript function that must be in one of their libraries. I don't see a reference to it in their docs myself other than in the recipe you've linked to. The documentation sections that reference obtaining the document height and width & dynamically resizing documents, do not mention it.